# How to resolve CA 1009 warning in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, .net-assembly

I have some C# code that loads an assembly from a certain path like so:

`assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);`

When I compile, Visual Studio Code Analysis throws this [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385973.aspx):

`warning : CA2001 : Microsoft.Reliability : Remove the call to Assembly.LoadFrom ...`

I'm looking for a way to resolve this warning (without suppressing it). Is there an alternative to `LoadFrom` that'll do that for me (I know `LoadFile` [isn't it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385973.aspx))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code *works* and *does what you expect*, then overrule the warning. The warning is there to bring your attention to things that might have edge-cases. If you have read what it *says* about CA 1009, and you understand the caveats, then: move on.

For loading from a specific path, `LoadFrom` may be the correct call. The only ways to totally remove that would be to:

- remove the requirement to load from a specific path
- use a custom `AppDomain` with different probing-paths, and use `MarshalByRefObject` to chat between them

Answer (score 3):

This in practice does the same but avoids the CA warning:

```
assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName { CodeBase = fileToLoadFullName })
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx) says "Do not use an `AssemblyName` with only the `CodeBase` property set." If you want to avoid the warning, you should just explicitly suppress it with `[SuppressMessage]` instead of working around FxCop.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you *might* be able to use `Assembly.Load`. This way your assembly can be in the GAC or your local bin directory.

```
var sampleAssembly = Assembly.Load("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3");
```